# Excel formula - Need value from a range based on the contents of another cell. Part 2

Tags: excel-formula, aggregate-functions, excel-2016

The following formula works great for the most part.  I found the solution to my first issue, which was how to return a value based on partial contents of another cell.  [Check out Scott Craner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142185/how-can-i-write-an-excel-formula-to-return-a-value-from-a-range-based-on-the-con).  Works great! However, when I started entering numbers I get the #NUM! error.

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & $C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)) & " "," " & A1 & " "))),1))
```

[image: #NUM! Screen clip]

I'm thinking that I'm getting the error because there are "." in the string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to include the formula:  =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & $C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)) & " "," " & A1 & " "))),1))

Comment: Put the formula in your actual question by editing the question.

Comment: Thanks Victor.  Not too sure about the proper etiquette on StackOverflow.

Comment: The formula you have doesn't work in that case because of what Scott pointed out in his answer: "The SEARCH will search for matches. The " " & and & " " make sure we are looking for the entire word, So we do not get false positives on things like eric and erica.." You could remove those from his formula - `=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)),A1))),1))` to make `B5` return what you want - which is not a whole "word" but a *part* of `A5` - but that might allow for false positives. Row 5 is not the same scenario as 1-4.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks BigBen.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you have doesn't work in that case because of what Scott pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142185/how-can-i-write-an-excel-formula-to-return-a-value-from-a-range-based-on-the-con):

> "The SEARCH will search for matches. The " " & and & " " make sure we are looking for the entire word, So we do not get false positives on things like eric and erica.."

You could remove those spaces from his formula, i.e.

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)),A1))),1))
```

to make `B5` return what you want - which is not a whole "word" but a part of `A5`, but as a caveat that might allow for false positives. Row 5 is not the same scenario as 1-4. So take this answer with a grain of salt, depending on your data.